# Flexbox: É possível forçar 100% de largura em uma div filha com space-between no pai?

Tags: css3, flexbox

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma div pai englobando três elementos, e ela possui o css:

```
.pai{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    width:400px;
}
```

Porém eu queria que a primeira filha ocupasse 100% da div e as outras duas ficassem com o *space-between*, é possível força-la a ocupar 100% mesmo com o justify-content no pai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode forçar o tamanho, sem problemas:

```css
.pai {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filha {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.filha:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <div class="filha">Teste</div>
  <div class="filha">Teste</div>
  <div class="filha">teste</div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito, era o flex-wrap que faltava :)

Comment: http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html e https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ são ótimos guias. E não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta, se ela solucionou o seu problema ;)